# Passing a Function (with parameters) as a parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

I want to create a generic to which I can pass a function as a parameter, however this function may include parameters itself so...

```
int foo = GetCachedValue("LastFoo", methodToGetFoo)
```

Such that:

```
protected int methodToGetFoo(DateTime today)
{ return 2; // example only }
```

Essentially I want to have a method that will check the cache for a value, otherwise will generate the value based on the passed in method.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but as a note, this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with generics as far as I can tell.

Comment: It kind of does, a little bit, maybe.  Probably "delegates" should replace "generics."

Comment: Sorry, I was creating a generic method to handle this, so I sorta assumed it was related.  But the passing is truly delegate related, so I will update.  Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `Func<T>`:

```
T GetCachedValue<T>(string key, Func<T> method) {
     T value;
     if(!cache.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
         value = method();
         cache[key] = value;
     }
     return value;
}
```

The caller can then wrap this in many ways; for simple functions:

```
int i = GetCachedValue("Foo", GetNextValue);
...
int GetNextValue() {...}
```

or where arguments are involved, a closure:

```
var bar = ...
int i = GetCachedValue("Foo", () => GetNextValue(bar));
```

Comment: Thanks I was very close, but could not figure how to get the parms right in the generic.  The last option, with the closure was the key!   Works like a charm.

Comment: Really old one here but the closure part was just what I was looking for

Answer (score 17):

Use `System.Action` and a lambda expression (anonymous method). For example:

```
public void myMethod(int integer) {     
    // Do something
}

public void passFunction(System.Action methodWithParameters) {
    // Invoke
    methodWithParameters();
}

// ...

// Pass anonymous method using lambda expression
passFunction(() => myMethod(1234));
```

Comment: Do I understand it right,  () => myMethod(1234) is wrapping the parametrized method in a non-parametrized method as a return value?

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own delegate, but in C# 3.0 you may find it more convenient to use the built-in `Func<T>` delegate family to solve this problem.  Example:

```
public int GetCachedValue(string p1, int p2,
                          Func<DateTime, int> getCachedValue)
{
    // do some stuff in here
    // you can call getCachedValue like any normal function from within here
}
```

This method will take three arguments:  a string, an int, and a function that takes a DateTime and returns an int.  For example:

```
int foo = GetCachedValue("blah", 5, methodToGetFoo);   // using your method
int bar = GetCachedValue("fuzz", 1, d => d.TotalDays); // using a lambda
```

Different `Func<T, U, V...>` etc. types exist in the framework to accommodate methods with different amounts of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Create a delegate for the method `methodToGetFoo`

```
public delegate object GenerateValue(params p);
public event GenerateValue OnGenerateValue;
```

Define GetCachedValue to use the delegate

```
int GetCachedValue(string key, GenerateValue functionToCall);
```

Then in the implementation of OnGenerateValue you can check the param's.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://xacc.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/simple-memomization-with-linq/) is something simple I started that can be taken a bit further (as I did for a commercial project).

In my case this was to cache web service calls, and was used something like:

```
WebService ws = new WebService();
var result = ws.Call( x => x.Foo("bar", 1));  // x is the ws instance
```